# List view row set atribute div with two buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm building a mobile app with jquery mobile 1.4.3, I'm trying to create a list-view where each row has 2 buttons.
The problem is that, the "div", with the buttons that I'm inserting, does not appear, here is the fiddle example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/claire89/kac5LyL8/4/)

Code sample:

```
var $menuList = $("#suggestions-list");

$menuList.empty();

var listItem = document.createElement("li");
var divForButtons = document.createElement("div");
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
var buttonAdd = document.createElement("a");
var buttonDelete = document.createElement("a");
var header1 = document.createElement("h1");
var header = document.createElement("h3");
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");

anchor.setAttribute("href", "");
anchor.setAttribute("data-id", "hey");

header.textContent = "something";
header1.textContent = "hello";
paragraph.textContent = "10" + "€";

buttonAdd.setAttribute("href", "#");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-role", "button");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("id", "btnUserSugAdd");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-id", "1");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("class", "split-custom-button");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-icon", "plus");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-rel", "dialog");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-theme", "c");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-iconpos", "notext");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-icon-position", "right");

buttonDelete.setAttribute("href", "#");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("align", "left");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-role", "button");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("id", "btnUserSugDel");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-id", "2");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("class", "split-custom-button");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-icon", "delete");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-rel", "dialog");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-theme", "c");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-iconpos", "notext");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-icon-position", "left");


divForButtons.appendChild(buttonAdd);
divForButtons.appendChild(buttonDelete);

anchor.appendChild(header);
anchor.appendChild(header1);
anchor.appendChild(paragraph);

listItem.appendChild(anchor);
listItem.appendChild(divForButtons);

$menuList.append(listItem);


$menuList.listview('refresh');
```

Comment: do you want the buttons side-by-side, or one on top of the other? Where in the listitem should they appear (All the way left, all the way right, before arrow icon, right after text, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put the demo link first and then explain:

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/kac5LyL8/8/)**

Add a class to the `<UL>` (e.g. has-editBtns):

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="suggestions-list" class="has-editBtns">
</ul>
```

Give the divForButtons `<DIV>` a class of editBtns, and use the jQM 1.4 classes for the buttons:

```
var listItem = document.createElement("li");
var divForButtons = document.createElement("div");
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
var buttonAdd = document.createElement("a");
var buttonDelete = document.createElement("a");
var header1 = document.createElement("h1");
var header = document.createElement("h3");
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");

anchor.setAttribute("href", "");
anchor.setAttribute("data-id", "hey");

header.textContent = "something";
header1.textContent = "hello";
paragraph.textContent = "10" + "€";

buttonAdd.setAttribute("href", "#");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("id", "btnUserSugAdd");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-id", "1");
buttonAdd.setAttribute("class", "ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all");

buttonDelete.setAttribute("href", "#");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("id", "btnUserSugDel");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-id", "2");
buttonDelete.setAttribute("class", "ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all");

divForButtons.setAttribute("class", "editBtns");
divForButtons.appendChild(buttonAdd);
divForButtons.appendChild(buttonDelete);

anchor.appendChild(header);
anchor.appendChild(header1);
anchor.appendChild(paragraph);

listItem.appendChild(anchor);
listItem.appendChild(divForButtons);
```

Finally add some CSS rules for these classes:

```
.has-editBtns li > a {
    margin-left: 40px !important;
}
.editBtns {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 39px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
.editBtns a:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.editBtns a:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

This moves the main link to the right leaving room for the buttons. The buttons div is absolutely placed on the left with the 2 buttons one above the other.

Answer (score 2):

They appear. Just don't have text inside. Try this:

```
var $menuList = $("#suggestions-list");

$menuList.empty(); 

    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var divForButtons = document.createElement("div");
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    var buttonAdd = document.createElement("a");
    var buttonDelete = document.createElement("a");
    var header1 = document.createElement("h1");
    var header = document.createElement("h3");
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");

    anchor.setAttribute("href", "");
    anchor.setAttribute("data-id", "hey");

    header.textContent = "something";
    header1.textContent = "hello";
    paragraph.textContent = "10" + "€";

    buttonAdd.setAttribute("href", "#");
    buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-role", "button");
    buttonAdd.setAttribute("id", "btnUserSugAdd");
    buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-id", "1");
    buttonAdd.setAttribute("class", "split-custom-button");
    buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-icon", "plus");
    buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-rel", "dialog");
    buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-theme", "c");
    buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-iconpos", "notext");
    buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-icon-position", "right");
    buttonAdd.text = "Add";//add text to button add

    buttonDelete.setAttribute("href", "#");
    buttonDelete.setAttribute("align", "left");
    buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-role", "button");
    buttonDelete.setAttribute("id", "btnUserSugDel");
    buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-id", "2");
    buttonDelete.setAttribute("class", "split-custom-button");
    buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-icon", "delete");
    buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-rel", "dialog");
    buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-theme", "c");
    buttonDelete.setAttribute("data-iconpos", "notext");       
    buttonAdd.setAttribute("data-icon-position", "left");
    buttonDelete.text = "Delete"; //Add text to button delete


    divForButtons.appendChild(buttonAdd);
    divForButtons.appendChild(buttonDelete);

    anchor.appendChild(header);
    anchor.appendChild(header1);
    anchor.appendChild(paragraph);

    listItem.appendChild(anchor);
    listItem.appendChild(divForButtons);

    $menuList.append(listItem);


$menuList.listview('refresh');
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kac5LyL8/7/)

Answer (score 2):

set some text to see the anchor element

> ```
> buttonAdd.innerHTML='A';
> ```

Comment: No offence but why you posted exactly the same answer as me after 4 mins?:P

Comment: [How to deal with duplicate answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252795/how-to-deal-with-duplicate-answers)

Comment: @Alek, actually it took me some time to debug in Chrome Developer Tool, and find the empty anchor in Dom Elements

Comment: Yes i understand and that is the reason i didn't downvote you. But as you see i answer some time earlier and you can either upvote/downvote my answer or post a different one. :)